# Citizen Patrol badge not awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I flagged a question as spam and even though some time has past (30m), I was not awarded the badge Citizen Patrol. Do I misunderstand what it is awarded for, or could it be that the badge did not get awarded as the question was deleted before the next award run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar issue in June & I e-mailed team@stackoverflow.

This is their response:

> It's definitely being awarded, I see
>   awards on 6-24, 6-22 x2, 6-21 x2, 6-20
>   x2.. etc.
>
> Oh wait, we did break out the spam /
>   offensive / inform moderator votes, so
>   I need to add all 3 of those types,
>   not just one!
>
> OK, the query has been updated. Thanks
>   for letting us know..

So it should be working now, though now you come to mention it I've flagged a couple of posts here as "inform moderator" and haven't had the badge either.

**UPDATE** I've just flagged a post over on SU (it's gone now so I can't provide the link) & haven't received the badge over there either. Something is definitely amiss.

**UPDATE 2** I've just flagged a post on SF as spam and that earned me the badge over there. I think it's a problem with the "inform moderator" vote.

**UPDATE 3** From Jeff's comment on his answer:

> oh, I see. This is only awarded for
>   spam and offensive flags, as we moved
>   the mod flags to another table. So if
>   you really want it, flag
>   spam/offensive

So the Citizen Patrol badge is only awarded when flagging a post as spam or offensive.

**UPDATE 4**

This is now no longer the case. Any flag causes the badge to be awarded.

> 2011-02-09: Flagging for moderator attention now counts for the Citizen Patrol badge. This change applies retroactively.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

Comment: This has been a recurring issue that has led to a lot of confusion and I don't think it has been resolved (or at least not explained to us clearly).

Comment: I agreed. I flaged 2 or 3 posts as informing users. It will be better if it is more well explained