# badge not received for flagging

Tags: support, badges, badge-request

I've flagged at least 2 posts to be moved to SF on SO today. but I haven't received a badge for flagging. Why not?

UPDATE:
I flagged them 'requires moderator attention' and left a message that they should be moved to SF

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/citizen-patrol-badge-not-awarded

Comment: AFAIK that isn't a "flag" (meaning: spam, offensive, etc) - it is a close vote...?

Comment: @Marc updated to reflect what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got that badge. see https://serverfault.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol and [your profile](https://serverfault.com/users/6852/xenoterracide) at serverfault. And that badge cannot get multiple times.

Comment: I just got on SF yes... but I think that's for the one I just marked as spam. not the ones I marked to be moved to SF. shouldn't the ones I marked to be moved give me the badge on SO?

Comment: flagging as moderation attention cannot get a badge, and that badge is only one time award.

Comment: oic. that's unfortunate but does explain it.