# Persisting lack of clarity on the operation of the Citizen Patrol badge

Tags: support, badges

Today, I received the Citizen Patrol badge. This came as a surprise, and arose from a slightly odd set of circumstances. I therefore looked here on Meta for clarification, and found [these links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/citizen-patrol-badge-not-awarded) about the badge. From these it seems that there was (and is) some uncertainty about how this badge operates. Could the description of the badge be edited to reflect how it ACTUALLY works. I would also appreciate a clear description of this badge here on Meta.

The circumstances under which my badge were awarded were:

I raised a flag for moderator attention on a [longish question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911658/pros-and-cons-of-different-schema-designs-for-tables-that-all-have-a-relationship) I had asked as, in the light of further thinking about the problem in the light of the first answer, I had realised that it was a damn stupid question. I raised the flag so as to obtain advice from the moderators, which I duly obtained and acted upon. I have now been awarded the Citizen Patrol badge for this action, which either shows that I had misunderstood the basis for this badge, or was inadvertently "gaming" the system.

Comment: Not sure whether I see the problem? You flagged something; you got the badge. Making people familiar with the flagging function is probably the main point of the badge, so it's mission accomplished

Comment: @Pekka - fair comment. I suppose my surprise was due to me flagging my own post and receiving the badge for that.

Comment: @Pekka, this may be coincidence, but the rules for the Citizen Patrol badge were changed today too... (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: @Benjol very useful link to my many "why does it work like that?" musings.