# Why there is no badges for helpful flags?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Its like Stack Exchange sites have badges awarded for almost every small contribution you do for the site, but why there are no helpful flags badges?

A bronze badge for starting up the task of reporting the helpful flags and 50 a silver badge and 250 or 500 helpful flags should be awarded a gold badge. I don't know the reason no badges are awarded for these questions we flag as helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*cough cough*

> [image]

Comment: Does "First flagged post" have to be helpful?

Comment: Excellent question @Tim, worth asking if not asked before. *grabs a walking stick and going to explore MSE woods in search of answer :)*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115512/change-the-requirement-for-citizen-patrol I don't think it was changed

Comment: @Tim missed it, nice find! So, you got an answer to your question... :-)